# Best way to combine SQL result? 2 request versus 1?

Tags: php, sql

What is the best practice to get posts with comments?

```
        // get posts
        $posts = query('
            SELECT  id,
                    content
            FROM    posts
            WHERE   author_id = 3
        ');

        // get post ids
        $post_ids = [];
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $post_ids[] = $post->id;
        }

        //get comment
        $comments = $this->db->query('
                SELECT  id,
                        content
                FROM    comments
                WHERE   post_id IN ('.implode(',',$post_ids ).')
            ');

        //Add to post
        $comments_by_id = [];
        foreach( $comments  as $comment ){
            $comments_by_id[$comment->post_id][] = $comment;    
        }

        //add comment to post
        foreach ($posts as &$post) {
            if (isset($comments_by_id[$post->id])){
                $post->comments = $comments_by_id[$post->id];
            }
        }
```

I could also achieve that with 1 query using `group_concat`.

```
SELECT p.id, p.content, GROUP_CONCAT(c.content)
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.author_id = 3
GROUP BY p.id, p.content
```

The end result is to have $posts that contains id, content, comments (in array)

Which one is better? Is there a better way?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: .. or use sub-query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Yes i simplified this version, as it's only about best practice, not the query itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, when it comes to manipulating structured data, it is more efficient to let your RDBMS do the heavy lifting.

You seem to be looking for a simple `JOIN` between `posts` and `comments`. The `FROM` clause should look like:

```
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
```

It is fairly unclear how you  want to arrange the dataset after joining, but since you mentionned `GROUP_CONCAT()`, here is an aggregate query that will return one record for each post, with all the correspoding comments concatenated (with a `,` separator):

```
SELECT p.id, p.content, GROUP_CONCAT(c.content)
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.author_id = 3
GROUP BY p.id, p.content
```

Comment: yes I was think of this alternative. So everyone seems to go for 1 query